# Who(several users) viewed particular Record(detail page) last in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have one Lightning requirement for display all Users (**FirstName, LastName**) detail who viewed particular single Case record(Case detail page) several times.

Suppose, I have a Case record with **Case Number**: "00007901", I just visited this record and after that other User visited same Case record. At that time, I need to display both visited Users detail on particular record detail page.

**Snapshot:**
[image: Like, multiple users viewed this record.]

Please help me for this issue, as i'm new on Lightning development.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this using Custom-settings.

**1.** Create  a list type custom-setting with three fields, on for the id of the user, one for name, and one integer field that stores the number of visits.

**2.** Everytime your lightning component loads, call a server side method in `doInit` and insert the custom setting record with the id of the user for future references.

**3.** Access the custom setting record for viewing the information on your other page.

Comment: It is not recommended to do DML in your init/afterRender handler because it introduces an security vector (CSRF) as mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Security)

Comment: In that case you can use afterScriptsLoaded. See more here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm